# C# interop.excel get_range call failing with Null Reference exception

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to access values in a worksheet within a Windows Forms app. I first open the spreadsheet file via a button (btnBrowse), and then once its open, the user enters a cell value in a textbox (txtBatchIDCell), and the contents of the value is displayed in another text box (txtBatchID).

However while I can query the cells (using getRange) within the function that first opens the spreadsheet, I can't query them within the txtBatchIDCell_textchanged subroutine, I get a null reference error (even if I hardcode the cell value into the get_Range call:

```
public partial class ImportXLS : Form
{
  public Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
  public Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
  public Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
  public object none = Type.Missing;

    public ImportXLS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        txtSpreadsheet.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(
                    txtSpreadsheet.Text, //FileName
                    0, //UpdateLinks
                    true, //ReadOnly
                    5, //Format
                    none, //Password
                    none, //WriteResPassword
                    true,//IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, //Origin
                    "\t", //Delimiter
                    false, //Editable
                    false, //Notify
                    0, //Converter
                    false, //AddToMRU
                    1, //Local
                    0 //CorruptLoad
                    );
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //get worksheet
                MessageBox.Show("Sheet open!");
    }
    private void txtBatchIDCell_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            txtBatchID.Text = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(txtBatchIDCell.Text, txtBatchIDCell.Text).Value2.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've made the workbook public but it's still giving me the same NullReference exception.

UPDATE:

the get_range call is now not working within btnBrowse either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Turns out it was actually working fine, except the cell in question was empty, hence why it was throwing the exception, which I was not expecting it would come back with.

Comment: So the moral of the story is.. Don't _assume_ objects are no null if you obtain them from a function and have documented proof that they cannot be null.  Note that you do that a few times in `btnBrowse_Click` as well.

Comment: @DStanley, Is there documented proof that get_Range() or the worksheet cannot be null?  All I can find for get_Range documentation is one very sparse page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bdftzxf9(v=vs.120).